# Git: how to remove all commits which are not connected with any existing files in repository

Tags: git

I am looking for a command which will remove all commits which are not connected to existing files.

In an example, if I remove file `XXX.txt` two months ago (one commit with one file deletion) I want to remove that commit from git history.

Comment: Why would you want to remove such commits?

Comment: I filter-branch from other repository and delete multiple files which are not related in IDE. I could probably do multiple filter-branch commands for multiple folders, but it was much faster. Then I need to remove commits related to deleted files.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not the way you should work with git. If you remove some commits you have to rewrite the history. If you delete a file the file is still present in the system otherwise you can't revert to an older state.

The problem is that all commits (history) are a tree and are connected to each other. From some of them you have made new branches. So if you want to delete an older commit your history isn't correct and you have to rewrite the history.

In some cases you can use **Rebase** and **Cherrypick**. Take a look here:

https://www.clock.co.uk/insight/deleting-a-git-commit